# RouteConfig is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routeconfig

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mApj7.png)

While running the project in visual studio; I am getting the error as in the attached image.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }   
        //Attendance, Timetable
    );
}
```

I put the break-point on the opening bracket. But it is not working.
This problem happened just 1 hour before. 
Please tell me solution to solve the problem. Because this project is plans to release soon. 
By expecting a good solution, Sibin

Comment: What is not working? - that is just the standard  default route.

Comment: Sir, I put the break-point in the opening bracket     " public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) { " ,     but while running the project, the break point is not working.   RouteConfig.cs is not working

Comment: Show your `Index()` method in `HomeController`

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
 {
       return View();
 }

Comment: Sir, while starting project, first it will move to RouteConfig.  I put the break point there.  But break point is not working in RouteConfig page

Comment: check your Global.asax file.   `protected void Application_Start()
        {           
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }`    the above code should be there in Global.aspx file.

Comment: I just had this problem on an old hobby project of mine I returned to for a bit of maintenance.  I renamed the assembly and all the namespaces but didn't remove some of the references from web.config files in subfolders, namely in the <namespaces> element.  Once I did that it was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a controller named `HomeController`, an ActionResult named `Index` and a `view` for the same.

Also check your `Global.asax.cs`, It must contain the following code

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```